# How to add custom css in Ionic 3

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic3

I have a html page written in Ionic. I want to add border bottom to every row in the grid. How can I do that.

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <img src='../assets/imgs/doctor.png'>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-10>
        {{item}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in you `app.scss`:

```
ion-row {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

It will add border bottom to every row.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom css as global or to specific component only

Here is the difference

- app.scss(Global) is the main .scss file. It is used to declare any
  styles that will be used globally throughout the application.
  Although it is the “main” .scss file, you won’t likely use it often –
  most of the styling will happen in the component specific .scss
  files.
- You will also have one .scss for each component you create. When we
  create a Page, we have a class definition in the .ts file, the
  template in the .html file and any styles for the component in the
  .scss file. Although it’s not strictly required, you should always
  create the .scss file for any components that have styling. And style
  in .scss is used for specific component only.

Now its you choice where you want to use following lines of css code

```
ion-row {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component is "example"

example.scss:

```
page-example {
  ion-row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for "scoped" css